No speakers sound Ubuntu 24.04
I have no sound in my laptop. I have Windows dual boot and the speakers work in Windows.
My laptop model is 'HP Envy x360 2-in-1 Laptop 15t-fe000'
I had the same issue in Ubuntu 23.10 so I did a fresh install of 24.04 and I still have the issue. I made sure nothing was muted in alsamixer, the right output is selected, I installed pulseaudio.
I also blacklisted

snd_soc_avs

to see if it was this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pipewire/+bug/2063150
And nothing has worked.
My audio devices

aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I don't really know what else to do

Were you able to make this work? I have the same problem.
